# xxd output without line breaks

Tags: xxd

Can I tell `xxd` to not print any line breaks in its output and have my dump as one continuous line?

```
[user@localhost] : ~ $ echo -n "this is a long line and xxd is going to take multiple lines to print it" | xxd -p
746869732069732061206c6f6e67206c696e6520616e6420787864206973
20676f696e6720746f2074616b65206d756c7469706c65206c696e657320
746f207072696e74206974
```

Comment: You could simply use `tr` to delete the newlines, e.g. `... | xxd -p | tr -d \\n`

Comment: It depends on what you need it for, but one handy option of `xxd` is that it ignores whitespace for the reverse `-r` of its postcript/plain `-p` dump (or any plain hexdump for that matter). eg. The following line wraps with `\n`, but the reversed output is exactly what was input:  `echo {1..14} | xxd -p | xxd -p -r` produces output: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14\n`  –  the `\n` is from the `echo`

Comment: You can also use `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"'` instead of `xxd`.

Comment: I'd stick with piping to `tr -d '[[:blank:][:space:]]'`.

Answer (score 28):

What you need is the -c option.

```
# echo -n "this is a long line and xxd will print it as one line" | xxd -p -c 1000000

746869732069732061206c6f6e67206c696e6520616e64207878642077696c6c207072696e74206974206173206f6e65206c696e65
```

Here is some info from the [documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html):

> -c  cols  | -cols cols format  octets per line. Default 16
>                 (-i: 12, -ps: 30, -b: 6). Max 256.

Documentation says that the max value for "c" parameter is 256, but I tried greater values and it worked. Check it out:

```
# xxd -c 1000000 -p -l 1000000 /dev/urandom | wc -c
2000001
```

Here I dump one million bytes from /dev/random and I get a string of 2 million + 1 characters. Each byte from /dev/random is represented by 2 characters and additional byte is the final newline.

Comment: With xxd version V1.10, it does not work: `xxd -c 10000`
`xxd: invalid number of columns (max. 256).`

Comment: @cdupont, you forgot the `-p` / `-ps`

Answer (score 8):

With `xxd` version 2022-01-14 (coming with [`vim` 8.2.4088](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/c0a1d370fa655cea9eaa74f5e605b95825dc9de1)) or newer, you can now use `-p` and `-c` with value 0 as said in the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/xxd.1.en#c):

> `-c` *cols* | `-cols` *cols*
>
> Format *cols* octets per line. Default 16 (`-i`: 12, `-ps`: 30, `-b`: 6). Max 256. No maximum for `-ps`. With `-ps`, 0 results in one long line of output.

For example:

```
$ echo "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." | xxd -p -c0 
4c6f72656d20497073756d2069732073696d706c792064756d6d792074657874206f6620746865207072696e74696e6720616e64207479706573657474696e6720696e6475737472792e0a
```

Comment: Just be careful that for previous version `-c 0` is just silently ignored instead of raising an error. Was burned by this today.